# Counterexample for interchanging integral and limit

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $f:\mathbb{R\to C}$ analytic. Assume that the integral $$I:=\int_0^1|x|^\alpha f(x)e^{\beta x}dx$$ converges. Prove or give counterexample that one can interchange summation and integration, that is $$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\int_0^1|x|^{n+\alpha}e^{\beta x}dx.$$

My intuition is that the presence of the $|x|^\alpha$ can lead to some counterexample I don't know how to build. Can one give me a hint?

Comment: @GuyFsone otherwise I wouldn't be able to write the Taylor expansion of $f$...

Comment: The Taylor series need not represent $f$ on the entire interval $[0,1]$. Try to play with a function whose Taylor series about $0$ represents the function only on a smaller interval. (Pick $\alpha = \beta = 0$ to remove artificial complications.)

Comment: @DanielFischer forgot to write they both can't be zero.

Comment: That doesn't really matter. If you have a counterexample that works for $\alpha = \beta = 0$, it's very very likely that it also works for nonzero $\alpha,\beta$ (maybe of small enough magnitude).

Comment: @DanielFischer another point: If $f$ is analytic on $[0,1]$, wouldn't you get the series converges to it?

Comment: No, $f$ being analytic just means that for every $a$ the Taylor series of $f$ about $a$ converges to $f$ on some neighbourhood of $a$. That neighbourhood can be much smaller than the domain.

Comment: @Heisenberg For example $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+2x^2}.$

Comment: @zhw. but for $\alpha=-2,\beta=5i,$ you get that both expressions diverge... Can we say that at least there is some asymptotic equality between the two expressions?

Comment: That was just an example of an analytic function on $\mathbb R$ whose Taylor explansion at $0$ doesn't converge everywhere on $[0,1].$